# Adjunctions between derived functors

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, derived-functors, adjoint-functors

Given an adjunction $F\dashv G$ between functors between Abelian categories, we know that $F$ is right exact and $G$ is left exact so there are derived functors $LF$ and $RG$ between (bounded above, respectively below) derived categories. What can one say about the existence of an adjunction $LF\dashv RG$?

Comment: A hypothesis I've found useful before with this question is that if the categories are Grothendieck abelian categories and $F$ is exact, then $LF$ and $RG$ are adjoint on bounded below derived categories. This follows immediately because $G$ preserves injective objects.

Comment: Is the category of finite dimensional modules over an algebra over a field a Grothendieck Abelian category? Does the same statement hold for the bounded above derived category, i.e. with projective objects?

Comment: The adjunction does always exist. It is a general fact, see MR2323740 (2008f:18011) Maltsiniotis, Georges Le théorème de Quillen, d'adjonction des foncteurs dérivés, revisité. (French) [Quillen's adjunction theorem for derived functors revisited] C. R. Math. Acad. Sci. Paris 344 (2007), no. 9, 549–552. http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611952

Comment: @Fernando: I don't see how to deduce that the adjunction always exists from the theorem you cited. The hypotheses are not dissimilar from what I wrote in my post above. (Note the author's use of the adjective "absolute").

Comment: @Eitan: No -- a Grothendieck abelian category is like the category of all modules over a ring. It has infinite direct sums, filtered colimits preserve monomorphisms, and it satisfies a (very mild) set-theoretic condition. But it doesn't really matter -- all that's important is the existence of enough injectives (which the Grothendieck condition implies). So the dual thing is satisfied if there are enough projectives.

Answer (score 3):

It seems this question was considered in:

William W Adams, Marc A Rieffel.
Adjoint functors and derived functors with an application to the cohomology of semigroups
Journal of Algebra, V. 7, N 1, 1967,  25-34

Comment: I can't find it online.

Comment: I believe this paper shows something slightly difference, but related, since in the end it uses preservation of injective objects.  There are a couple of versions in the paper depending on which categories have enough injectives or projectives.  Roughly it is concerned with a pair of adjoint exact functors $F,G$ and a third half exact functor $H$ such that say $H\circ G$ makes sense and it gives conditions so that $R(H\circ G)=H\circ RG$.  A typical special case is Shapiro's lemma: if $A$ is a subgroup of $B$, then $H^n(A,M)=H^n(B,Coind(M))$.